# Frequency Modulation Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

i want to make a continious sinwave which will change his frequency 3 times, like in the photo. I tryied with the `fmmod` function but i can't make it work, so is there any other way , thanks in advance.

[image]

here is my code

```
Fs = 44100; % Sampling rate of signal
Fc = 3000; % Carrier frequency
t = [0:Fs-1]'/Fs; % Sampling times
x = sin(2*pi*4000*t)+sin(2*pi*5000*t)+sin(2*pi*8000*t); % my signal

dev = 50; % Frequency deviation in modulated signal
y = fmmod(x,Fc,Fs,dev);
plot(y)
```

Comment: Why can't you make fmmod work?

Comment: let's say f1=4000Hz , f2=5000Hz and f3=8000Hz (not as in the picture ) the fmmod can't combine these 3 different frequencies , this function has the following syntax y = fmmod(x,Fc,Fs,freqdev) , where x is my sinwave , fc is the carrier frequency and fs is sampling , so how can i implement ?

Comment: show a bit of the code you tried, and give more details. How long each block of frequency should be ? should the change be abrupt or progressive, what is the sampling rate of the overal curve (is it even constant ?)  ... etc

Comment: lets say each block 1000 samples and the change should be abrupt, any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequency modulation without fmmod:

```
Fs = 44100; % Sampling rate of signal
T=1/Fs; % period

t = 0:T:0.01; % sample times

% amplitude of message signal
vm = 5
% amplitude of carrier signal 
vc =5
% message frequency 
fm =500
% carrier freq
fc = 5e3
% modulation index
m =5

figure

y = vc*sin(2*pi*fc*t+m.*cos(2*pi*fm*t));
plot(t,y);
```

Comment: it's without fmmod , anyway i will accept your answer as i can create 3 different signals with 3 different frequencies and then create my final signal combining them

Comment: Thanks. I meant to say "without fmmod" when I posted. I will correct the title.